# powershell get IP on bond interface of VMs on Hyperv

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, powershell, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

I have a hyperV host and a ubuntu is running on it with hyperV integration packages.

On the virtual machine I have a physical interface eth0 and a bond interface (For testing purpose, this bond interface only contains one physical interface eth0).

I'm using Get-VMNetworkAdapter to get IPAddressess on the VM.

However I can only get IP on eth0, not bond0 (Guess that makes sense as the command I'm calling is get "network adapter" and the only network adapter can be retrieved is the one for eth0)

How can I get the IP on bond interface using powershell?

Comment: That may not be possible. bond interface is managed inside VM i.e. Linux kernel not in Hyper-V. Though Windows Server has similar feature named NIC Teaming.

Comment: thx, i think u r right

Comment: If you are interested in some socket programming then checkout `hvsocket.h` file in Windows SDK.